# Discord Selfbot in discord.py rewrite command not found

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a selfbot for discord in discord.py rewrite and it gives me this error:

`Ignoring exception in command None:`
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "me" is not found`

Here is my code:

````
from discord.ext import commands

selfbot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "<.", self_bot = True)

selfbot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'IDK Running on: {selfbot.user}')

selfbot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Off.')

selfbot.command()
async def me(ctx):
    ctx.send(f'You are {selfbot.user}')

token = 'token here'
selfbot.run(token, bot = False)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing `@`. It should've been

```
from discord.ext import commands

selfbot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "<.", self_bot = True)

@selfbot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'IDK Running on: {selfbot.user}')

@selfbot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Off.')

@selfbot.command()
async def me(ctx):
    ctx.send(f'You are {selfbot.user}')

token = 'token here'
selfbot.run(token, bot = False)
```

Note: You're missing the command decorator main thing, `@`, without it, your command will not register as a command or a event